# Need to push values of an array into a variable as a string

Tags: php

Need to push values of an array as like ('1','2','3'........) in a $variable. I have a while loop from where I am getting the values 1,2,3.... I am doing like this

```
while ($record = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {  
    $users_id = $record['user_id'];  
    $uid = array_push($users_id, ','); 
}
```

I need these values as a String in a variable, then I will use explode function to remove ',' and use it according to my need. Please anyone can help me in this.. Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand. Please make it clear, what is the input? What is the desired output? What are you getting differently?

Comment: well for starters, you aren't using `array_push` correctly.  The first arg is the array and the 2nd arg is the value. 2nd, the returned value is the new number of elements in the array (basically a `count($array)`.  If you just want an array of user ids, see xbonez answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding them to a string and exploding it will give you an array of the values. You can just directly push them to an array

```
$users_id = array();    

while ($record = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {  
    $users_id[] = $record['user_id'];  
}
```

Comment: When I do like this  $users_id[] = $record['user_id'];  
 

 $uid = array_push($users_id, ','); 

        var_dump($uid); it show me like this int(2) int(4) int(6)

Answer (score 0):

```
// open parens
$newString = "(";

// for each value add quotes and comma
foreach($users_id as $v) 
   $newString .= "'".$v."',";

// remove the trailing comma
$newString = substr($newString , 0, -1); 

// close parens
$newString .= ")";
```